# How I can use upsert, $inc, $set in sails?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

How do I use mongodb operations like "$inc, $set, upsert..." in sails.js using the sails-mongo adapter?

I've tried this code, but the adapter doesn't identify the options.

```
Word.update(
  {coincidence: 'aaaaa'},
  {amount: 222},
  {upsert:true,safe:true},
  function(err,data){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("score succeded");
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I added a missing closing parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `native` method of the model to do this.  It returns an instance of the native Mongo driver's collection:

```
Word.native(function(err, collection) {
  collection.update(
     {coincidence: 'aaaaa'},
     {amount: 222},
     {upsert:true,safe:true},
     function(err){
       if (err){
        console.log(err);
       } else {
        console.log("score succeded");
       }
     }
  );
});
```

See [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) for docs on the Mongo native driver, which will show you what you can do with the collection returned by the `native` method.

Comment: When using the native method, are the model's hook triggered ?

Comment: If you mean the lifecycle callbacks like `.beforeCreate` and `.afterUpdate`, then the answer is no.  You can always call then yourself though; they're just class methods like any other (e.g. `Word.beforeCreate(values, callback)`)